# How to config Intellij Idea to connect to MySql database in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, xampp

I want to connect to *XAMPP* *phpMyAdmin* through IntelliJ IDEA's database plugin. My settings are as follows:

- Host:      `localhost`
- Database:  `student`
- User:      `root`
- Password:  `[password]`
- URL:       `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student`

While testing connection I am getting "connection failed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining *MYSQL* path in Environmental Variables fixed the problem.

Path: C:\xampp\mysql\bin